# Is the option (rightclick on proj) publishWeb and webdeploy extension the same?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, package, msdeploy

I'm confused here, because I've never downloaded WebDeploy (msdeploy) but it's been some time since I use on my vs2010 (and 2012 too) the rightclick on webapp.csproj -> publish (which generates a .pubxml and makes the deploy happen).

Are those the same thing? and if not and I want to separate the deploy as the implementer's work, which is the best to do it?

I was thinking on passing to the msbuild a template with a somewhat embebed pubxml for it to do the magic. But IDK if it's possible or the best path

Comment: On passing .pubxml to msbuild see this tutorial, which is #10 in a multi-tutorial series:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment

Comment: Ok, seems useful, i'll be taking a look at it, thanks Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publish option allows you to publish the website to and FTP, Web Deploy, FSPE etc. Web deploy is a way of deploying the package. You must install the WebDeploy on the IIS server which allows you to use it.

For more information about WebDeploy: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx